# Install ubuntu 13.04 alongside windows 8

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, windows

Currently I am using Windows 8 in my dell N4050 machine. It has 4GB of RAM, 320GB HDD. Now I want to install ubuntu 13.04 alongside Windows. I tried several times after reading some blogs. But every time I failed.

I downloaded Ubuntu 32bit from the official site and made my pendrive into bootable device using Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.3.7.exe.

I could not burn a DVD and boot from it because my DVD drive is not working somehow.

By the way, I did all the normal stuff what is needed for installing Ubuntu. In installation process `Install ubuntu alongside windows 8` should have appeared but I just saw `Replace Ubuntu with Windows 8` and `Something else`. Then I tried going with `something else`, I did not see such option where I can chose to use ubuntu alongside windows.

Comment: Windows 8 preinstalled? first mistake is ubuntu 32bit. for UEFI enabled systems , 64bit ISO must be used. See [Installing on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 System (UEFI Supported)](http://askubuntu.com/q/221835)

Comment: Yes, I installed Windows 8 earlier. Then I tried Ubuntu 12.04 64bit. Can you lead me how to disable UEFI?

Comment: If you have installed windows 8 on your own, it doesn't called pre installed :). Only if the manufacturer has installed windows 8, then it is called preinstalled. UEFI can be disabled from  UEFI/BIOS menu which generally triggered by `F2` or `Del` in system startup. Check your laptop manual. **Warning** Disabling UEFI will cause windows 8 to stop working. You need to reinstall.

Comment: :o Alright. It seems I can not install Ubuntu on my machine and learn it. I am new in Linux OS.

Comment: Are you sure if I download Ubuntu 13.04 64bit and try again to install I won't face such an issue?

Comment: Yea, there shouldn't be any problem. But after installation you may face some error. See this before proceeding  to fix them https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: It seems that I read all your leads yesterday.... :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely have 64bit processor according to Dell Inspiron N4050 specs (http://www.specsbox.com/628/dell-inspiron-n4050-14-laptop.html), and all possible CPU specs (http://ark.intel.com/products/55627/Intel-Pentium-Processor-B950-2M-Cache-2_10-GHz) (http://ark.intel.com/products/53434/Intel-Core-i3-2330M-Processor-3M-Cache-2_20-GHz), (http://ark.intel.com/products/53450/Intel-Core-i5-2430M-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-3_00-GHz)

Use 64bit version of Ubuntu !